# Condition to be a Singular Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a rectangular matrix. Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are vectors so that $$x^T M = (x^T My) y^T.$$

Does this imply that $x$ and $y$ are singular vectors of $M$?

If M is square and $x=y$ then indeed this implies that $x$ must be an eigenvector of $M.$ This is because then $Mx = (x^T M x) x,$ where $x^TMx$ is a scalar, which implies that $x$ is an eigenvector. Not sure how to reason about this case for singular vectors though.

Comment: fixed, sorry! thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't imply this, I'm afraid. The equation is equivalent to the following condition:

> There exists some $\lambda$ such that $M^\top x = \lambda y$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\|y\| = 1$.

I hope I don't have to come up with a specific counterexample to prove this; all you'd need to do is start with any matrix $M^\top$, and any vector $x$ not in its nullspace that also is not a singular vector, and let $y$ be its normalisation. Let's prove this condition is equivalent.

If this condition holds, then either $M^\top x = 0$, in which case both sides are $0$, or $y^\top y = 1$, and some $\lambda$ exists such that $x^\top M = \lambda y^\top$. Subbing this into the equation yields
$$\lambda y^\top = \lambda y^\top y y^\top,$$
which are the same, as $y^\top y = 1$.

Now let's assume the equation holds true. If $x^\top M = 0$, then the equation is satisfied. Otherwise $x^\top M \neq 0$, which implies that $(x^\top M y)y^\top \neq 0$, implying that $x^\top M y \neq 0$. From here, we further see that
$$x^\top M y = (x^\top M y)(y^\top y)$$
which implies $\|y\| = 1$.

Now, in the original equation, it turns out the parentheses are superfluous: we can multiply the $1 \times 1$ matrix $x^\top M y$ to the row vector $y^\top$ without issue. So, rearranging, we obtain
$$x^\top M(I - yy^\top) = 0.$$
Given $\|y\| = 1$, $I - yy^\top$ is the orthogonal projection matrix onto $\{y\}^\perp$, which is the map's range. Thus $M^\top x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\{y\}^\perp$, hence $M^\top x \in (\{y\}^\perp)^\perp = \operatorname{span}(y)$. That is, $M^\top x$ is a scalar multiple of $y$, completing the proof.